# В Spring MVC классы модели как Beans - за и против?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

**Сам вопрос:** какие негативные (позитивные я знаю) стороны могут быть у инъекции модельных классов в Spring MVC?

**Контекст вопроса:** Spring нигде в продакшене не использовал, только для баловства да для будущей позиции посмотрел возможности Spring MVC, Boot, Cloud. 
Для себя давно решил по идеологии ООП, из опыта с Guice и Castle Windsor в других проектах, что все что можно, я отдаю фреймворкам инъекций, а что нельзя я заворачиваю и все равно отдаю на инъекции.

Нужно все это для юнит тестов. Все что нельзя протестировать - это либо уже говнокод, либо станет им через пару лет разработки, регрессионные баги, рефакторинг и т.д. и т.п. Без юнит тестов, даже если есть интеграционное тестирование - фидбек будет с лагом, который в зависимости от системы может в сутках измеряться.

На уже третьем (последнем техническом) собеседование при разборе моего тестового проекта в очень крупной и чисто софтовой конторе меня начинает один из 3 собеседующих крутить (под молчание остальных) - почему я модельные классы объявляю бинами. После моих развернутых и спокойных объяснений меня прокатили мимо позиции. И тут я задумался, может это прям пердец какой бэдпрактис в Spring?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Мне приходит в голову, что бины в спринге по умолчанию создаются синглтонами, что в случае модельных классов не логично

Comment: Я сейчас, скорее всего, соберу гору метафизических минусов, но спринг вообще не годится ни для тестирования, ни для серьезных проектов, это аналог yii в php-мире. Используя спринг вы либо откажетесь от всего функционала, либо не сможете ничего протестировать (и, честно гговоря, лучше отказаться от функционала, как по мне).

Comment: @Etki А что тогда годится? (ну так, для общего развития)

Comment: @enzo если честно, у меня не так много опыта с java-фреймворками, но в ближайшее время собираюсь потрогать dropwizard, quasar (насколько понимаю, сам по себе quasar всего лишь библиотека и к вебу отношения не имеет, но есть расширения веб-акторов) и akka. Понятно, что последние два это совсем не аналог спринга, но, если честно, мне в последнее время кажется, что подход спринга и аналогов в корне неверен.

Comment: @cadmy +1 аннотация и все. Я все же склоняюсь к тому, что в Спринге это как то просто не принято. Я сейчас на Гите просматриваю проекты, штук 5 - все без инъекций модели. А у меня там не просто классы были, я еще все всегда через интерфейсы проектирую, под них пишу первые тесты, а после реализация уже по второму кругу - дописываю тесты.

Comment: Вообщем на выходных сделаю все на без иок и прогоню тесты на скорость\нагрузку и сонар пускай мне посчитает как они друг против друга стоят.

Answer (score 3):

Инъекции ради инъекций? Бин модели должен быть максимально простым. Его задача - хранить данные. Таких объектов может быть огромное количество - о каждом хранить информацию к контексте? Главное - зачем? Юнит тесты? У вас не должно быть логики в бинах модели.

Comment: Модель в бинах легко как раз то мокать в контроллерах. От моков легче добиться нужного состояния, репродуцировать сложные состояния. Я вот думаю, бины (их какая то метаинформация) должны где там в контексте болтаться. А много ее там, особенно если речь о высоконагруженных?